# Play/pause music when screen locked?

Tags: lock-screen, rhythmbox, music-player

Is there a way to play/pause a media player when screen is locked?
I often listen to music, most of the time using [rhythmbox](/questions/tagged/rhythmbox) or VLC, on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. After a few minutes, the screen locks as expected but leaves me without a way to play/pause the music without loging in again.
I've heard about [pause-on-lock](https://github.com/folixg/pause-on-lock) but I'd like to be able to keep listening to music even on locked screen and avoid having to launch a script outside Xserver via keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Have you considered buying a keyboard with media keys? These should keep working when the screen is locked.

Comment: That'd be kind of overkill. Besides, I use a 14'' laptop, so it's not really an option.

Comment: @CelestinTaramarcaz rite now, if your screen is auto locked or you manually lock it when rhythmbox is playing music.. what is happening.. is it continuing the music or?

Comment: i am using `audacious` as the music player and it is possible with my keyboard which have media keys.

Comment: @PRATAP The music keeps playing when the screen locks (which it does automatically after 5 minutes or so). My keyboard sadly doesn't have such keys...

Answer (score 1):

go to keyboard shortcut section and find the "Sound and Media"
[image]

set the shortcuts to other key combos as you dont have media keys on your keyboard.

i have configured like below
[image]

i have tested them without lockscreen,
[image]

it worked on lockscreen also
[image]

Comment: Thanks @PRATAP for your thoroughly illustrated answer. It still doesn't work. I guess keyboard shortcuts don't work when the screen is locked (except for volume up/down and a few other ones, though). It's sad because that'd be a very simple and practical workaround.

Comment: did you check those keyboard shortcuts without locking the screen first? it worked for me even on lock screen but it is not visible in attached gif.

Comment: As expected, the keyboard shortcuts work when the screen isn't locked.

Comment: when you lock the screen, is the rhythmbox was playing and is it the opened window?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I keep my personal laptop on my desk while working so I can listen to music on it. It does have media keys but they require use of the Fn key which necessitated use of both hands for me. I changed the keyboard shortcuts to use the function keys shared by the media keys so now when the screen is locked, F10, F11 and F12 (single keys, not with Fn) will perform "previous", "play/pause" and "next", respectively.